# How do I modify the interval speed?

Tags: carousel, intervals, autoplay, ant-design-pro

This question is for this component: https://ant.design/components/carousel/#header

I have attempted autoplayInterval={1000} to no success.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the exact issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 4):

`autoPlaySpeed` is the prop that you want. You can set `autoPlaySpeed={1000}`, default value is 3000ms. The carousel component demo uses 'react-slick' and here is the [reference](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#autoplaySpeed) for *autoPlaySpeed*, you can also check rest of additional API's for this plugin. Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g6ujw1?file=index.js) code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you need autoplaySpeed={1000}, check letters

Comment: Did you mean `autoPlaySpeed`?